# ActionBar.OnNavigationListener deprecated

Tags: android

I know this has been asked before with reference to navigation, but the [Developer Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Dropdown) say

> As another mode of navigation (**or filtering**)

So, what would be the replacement for a spinner in the action bar which just requeries the database and updates the view depending on the selected option?

Answer (score 1):

This question es quite old but I give the answer anyway.

When you are migrating to v7 support library need to change the listener.

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
```

On Spinner creation

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this); //set the listener
```

Implement Listener Methods

```
  @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Snackbar.make(this.getCurrentFocus(), "OnItemSelected", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        //Your implementation here
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        Snackbar.make(this.getCurrentFocus(), "onNothingSelected", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        //Your implementation here
    }
```

onNothingSelected method used is not clear. You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439463/why-is-onnothingselected-method-needed-in-spinner-listener) post to clarify.

I hope it helps.

Regards