# What roles does event handling play in the role of spinners & buttons?

Tags: android, events, event-handling, android-spinner

I'm beginning to understand that an event occurs which is listened to, and then handled - this is obvious in the case of a button - onclicklistener & onmouseclick. Not sure if there is a onhover for a button, or how my undestanding of events are so far.

I'm curious as to how do events work in spinners, is there a listener or an onclick with a spinner. Coded one before and can't seem to understand the role of events.

Comment: You just want some clarification on when a spinner shows up and when it goes away?  And any events associated with a spinner?

Comment: Am I on the right track describing events with Buttons. Mainly would like to know what are the common two or three events used in a spinner view.

Comment: You are on the right track yes.  Most components have events of various kinds, things like `onhover`, `onclick`, `onselect`, etc. or some variation depending on your language and other factors.  On this page: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner#java it states that spinners can have a few events, one of which is `onItemSelected`.  This is probably the most commonly used one along with `onNothingSelected` as they can be used to populate other fields based on selections and such.

Comment: Thanks Michael - another quick question -> why is there a need for onNothingSelected if the items in a spinner are already there?

Comment: Check out this post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439463/why-is-onnothingselected-method-needed-in-spinner-listener  It answers and links to the docs that can probably explain a bit more in depth than me.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed responses- thanks again - will check that out